# how to reduce time out connecting to a informix instance

Tags: odbc, informix

I need to reduce the time to get an error when connecting to an unavailable instance.

The problem is that I can't modify the machine configuration. And currently I'm using the ODBC drivers.

The Informix client-sdk can be from 3.50 to 3.70tc3
the instance version is probably 10.x
and the clients run from windows XP thru Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the environment variable INFORMIXCONTIME to any value in seconds that fits your application